# Why is my setTimeout function not waiting for the time specified?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, settimeout

I have a for loop and I want to print its i'th value after a delay but with setTimeout() function, it waits for specified time but then every value of i prints without any delay. Is this because setTimeout() is an Async function and by the time it completes its first countdown, the time for all other values is also over.

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
   setTimeout(()=>{
     console.log(i);
   },10);
}
```

OUTPUT:
(10ms Gap) 1-2-3-4-5

OUTPUT REQUIRED: 1 - 10ms Gap - 2 -10ms Gap--... So on. Kindly provide the reason for solution.

Comment: `for` loops are synchronous. You're setting a bunch of `setTimeout` at the same time, to trigger in 10 milliseconds. Maybe you meant to use `10 * i` as a delay? (first one "immediately", second one in 10, third one in 20...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the `setTimeout` is asynchronous, therefore every `console.log(i)` is set to run at basically the same time.  I find it easier to use `setInterval` in your scenario:

```
let i = 0;
let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(i);
    i++;

    if (i === 10) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly calling `setTimeout()` in your loop, if you just want to delay your loop, you could try something like this.

```js
loopWithDelay();

async function loopWithDelay() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        console.log(i)
        await delay(100);
    }
}

var timer;
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise((x) => {
        timer = setTimeout(x, ms);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the timer in the loop for every item.

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
   setTimeout(()=>{
     console.log(i);
   },10*(i+1));
}
```

This ensures proper gap between every item.

I hope it helps.

Comment: to see the difference, try setting the millisecond to 1000 (1 second). So that you can see the desired result, i.e. 1000*(i+1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setTimeout() is an async function and all the countdowns start at almost the exact time because there is no waiting time between succesive setTimeout() calls.

What you can do in order to get the expected behaviour is put the for in a function and call that function back from setTimeout() when the countdown runs out:

```
function f(i) {
    if(i < 10) {
        setTimeout(()=> {
            console.log(i);
            f(i+1);
        }, 10);
     }
}
f(0);
```